# identify data type of column from table using NER models

Tags: nlp, python-3.x, named-entity-recognition, pyspark, aws

I have structure data with csv or parquet format, I would like to extract the data type of the column by analyzing the data.
when I looked at the NER from Hugging phase transformers, it actually dealing with context, but here my data is tabular format.
is there any way to extract data type of the each column by analyzing the data, actually volume of the data is so big (GB's), please suggest best solution for this.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by extracting the data type of each column? Have you tried the using the `dtypes` property?

Comment: Your question is not clear: normally the type of a column is just "string" or "integer" for instance. But you also talk about NER which assigns advanced semantic categories like "person name" or "location" (fyi the only way to do this without context requires a dictionary). Please give an example of input data and what you would expect as type.

Comment: Hi  Erwan &  DarknessPlusPlus, Thanks a lot for your response. currently data type of each column is string, by looking at the data, need to assign proper data type based on data, like int, big int, long, double and date etc... i understand when we go with NER, it will give category based on context, even if we get category , we will try map the category and get data type based on category. please let me know apart from NER, is there any better solution to deal with this problem

Comment: if you are interested in the technical data type only (like int, double, date...), this is *not* NER at all. Normally detecting types in python is simpler, see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/402504/891919) and afaik libraries for reading csv files can usually detect the correct type. You should probably give more detail about your data and your specific problem.